# Use Text Column to IF Statement in DAX

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

Im new to Power bi and trying to write a DAX function with IF condition.

Ex.

| Product | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1500 |
| B | 2000 |
| C | 3000 |

My formula to calculate value

```
VALUE =
IF (
    'ProductList'[Product] = "A",
    1500,
    IF (
        'ProductList'[Product] = "B",
        2000,
        IF (
            'ProductList'[Product] = "C",
            3000,
            0
        )
    )
)
```

It showing me an error in 'ProductList'[Product]. Because It does not allow me to refer text column.

Can anybody to help me to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to use this formula as a new column or a measure?

Answer (score 0):

Your DAX function is just fine. It only needs a *row context* to work. It has nothing to do with a *text* column. However, your question doesn't make clear what you actually want to achieve.

A *calculated column* will calculated values for each (horizontal) row, while a *calculated measure* will aggregate numbers (vertically) across rows.

[image]